# RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable throwing External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an Azure web role linked to a MVC web application (InitRole).  I have also configured another website (MainSite) to be deployed to the same web role by referencing the project using Site tags in the Service Definition file.

I am trying to use the `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` method to determine whether I should use a connection string from my role config or to retrieve from the web.config.  I am calling this method from a data access class library project by referencing the Azure service runtime dll.

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> InnerException = {"External component has thrown an exception."}

Can somebody shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to move that logic to the Webrole.cs file in the root of your web application.  Attempting to access the Azure fabric from a nested class library may be throwing the error because it can't access the environment information.

Can you try modifying your class to accept the connection string as a parameter from the WebRole : RoleEntryPoint OnStart() function, and performing the RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable check in that startup function?